# UWP:Frame in Frame Back handeling

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, back, handle

In my new UWP app, I have a Frame in a Frame that I want to handle the back button.
View looks like this :

[image: View]

Note:F = Frame , P=PAge, Red=Navigation, Blue=NavigationBack

I have a master page that can navigate to some pages. And one of those pages has an inner root frame that navigates to p4 onload. And p4 can be navigated to some pages.
The issue is that by Microsoft's way for navigation, I just can handle the root frame (f1) or just the inner frame (f2).

With this code :

```
public P3()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        else
            Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested +=
        App_BackRequested;
    }
    ~P3()
    {
        if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        else
            Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -=
         App_BackRequested;
    }

    private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (Frame == null)
            return;

        // Navigate back if possible, and if the event has not 
        // already been handled .
        if (Frame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Frame.GoBack();
        }


    }

    private void App_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Frame == null)
            return;

        // Navigate back if possible, and if the event has not 
        // already been handled .
        if (Frame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Frame.GoBack();
        }


    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        F2.Navigate(typeof(P4));

        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            // Show UI in title bar if opted-in and in-app backstack is not empty.
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
                AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove the UI from the title bar if in-app back stack is empty.
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
                AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Note: No need to check for hardware back button. Subscribing to `BackRequested` works for hardware or software back buttons.

Comment: Navigation can be handled with either frame. Just make sure to set e.Handled to true and check e.Handled for both. Looks like you're checking this for Page3, but how about your original Frame?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot I did it for both. But no result

Comment: Are you wanting to navigate back for both frames or just one? What frame is navigating back? Can you share code for your first frame?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot I want both frames to navigate back. If you look at the graph, if we are in P6 in F2, if we navigate back we should be in P4 and we if we press back again we should be in F1.
I Just copied the same code above in P3 (When you press back you'll go to F1 even if F2 is navigated to P6) and When I copied that code into P4 I just could navigate back from P5 & P6 to P4. Not from P3 to F1.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot When I duplicated the usage, After clicking back, It goes to F1 ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Page3 has a Frame in it called F2. This is the frame you want to use for navigating back. So you'll want to change your back navigation as such

```
public P3()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
}

private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (F2 == null)
        return;

    // Navigate back if possible, and if the event has not 
    // already been handled .
    if (F2.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        F2.GoBack();
    }
}
```

Note that you were using `Frame` which is a property on the Page itself that gives access to the parent Frame of the Page.

Comment: public P3()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
}

private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (F2 == null)
        return;

    // Navigate back if possible, and if the event has not 
    // already been handled .
    if (F2.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        F2.GoBack();
    }
 else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                Frame.GoBack();
            }
}

Comment: I used that code. It sometimes work and sometimes crashes :(

Comment: I Added this

else if (e.Handled == false)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                Frame.GoBack();
            }
It sometimes goes from P6 to F1 :|

Comment: With the code you have sent, I can navigate back within F2 pages but I can not navigate back from P3(Host of F2) to F1

Comment: When I navigate back to F1 and renavigate to p3 then navigate F2 to p5/p6, I understand that P2.CanGoBack is equal to False and BackStackDepth is 0 :(